# How to forward non-member functions via Swig (C#)?

Tags: c#, c++, swig

So I try to create std_complex.i (because there is no such in C# SWIG library out of the box). Here is what I tried:

```
%{
#include <complex>
%}

namespace std {
    template<class T>
    class complex {
    public:
        complex(T r, T i);
        complex(const complex<T> & other);

        T imag();

        T real();

        %rename(Add) operator+=;
        %rename(Substract) operator-=;
        %rename(Multiply) operator*=;
        %rename(Divide) operator/=;

        complex<T>& operator+= (const complex<T>& rhs);
        complex<T>& operator-= (const complex<T>& rhs);
        complex<T>& operator*= (const complex<T>& rhs);
        complex<T>& operator/= (const complex<T>& rhs);
    };
}

%template(Complex) std::complex<double>;
```

Resulting wrapper does perform class member operations yet I cant get how to forward [non member functions of `std::complex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/operators/) operators such as `==`, or `+` for example. So how to forward non-member functions in SWIG C#?

For examle this one `operator+`:

```
template<class T> complex<T> operator+(const complex<T>& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
template<class T> complex<T> operator+(const complex<T>& lhs, const T& val);
template<class T> complex<T> operator+(const T& val, const complex<T>& rhs);
```

?